# How to select correct oracle.ManagedDataAccess package version for 19c database With oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework

Tags: oracle, .net-framework-version, oracle.manageddataaccess

I am working with an Oracle Database with **runtime 19.3.0.0 on server-side.**

I have a **.NetFW 4.6.1** client that needs connecting to this DB using **oracle.ManagedDataAccess** package

When I look at the Package Manager I get multiple options for **oracle.ManagedDataAccess** package for 19c
ranging from *19.3.0 - 19.8.0* (Latest Stable).

[image]

**How to chose the correct version ?**

Comment: Does not matter. Every client >12.1 should work.

Comment: My question had a caveat, I was using EntityFw package as well, this was bottle-necking.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this out since I could not get the answers from oracle support via my data-warehouse provider.

### **Conclusion**

**oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.2.1100** was **NOT** happy to deal with 19.3.0.0 serverside when pared with **oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.2.1100**

### **Minimum Tested Working Combo - Did not test below 12.2.xx**

**oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.2.1100** was working with **19.3.0.0 serverside** when pared with **oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.2.20190115**

### **Maximum Tested Upto - As At 2020-08-10**

**oracle.ManagedDataAccess 19.7.0** was working with **19.3.0.0 serverside** when pared with **oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 19.7.0**

This was also backward compatible with Oracle **serverside 12.2.0.1.0**